# Getting repeated values after use Group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this one:

```
+------------+---------------+--------------------------+---------+
| GeneralKey |     Label     |         Extended         | OrderID |
+------------+---------------+--------------------------+---------+
|         63 | Take-Off      | Project Status           |       1 |
|         64 | Hold          | Project Status           |       3 |
|         65 | Pending       | Project Status           |       5 |
|         66 | Contracted    | Project Status           |       6 |
|         67 | Dead          | Project Status           |       7 |
|         86 | Pricing       | Project Status           |       4 |
|         99 | Bid Request   | Project Status           |       0 |
|        100 | Take-Off      | Design Contracted Status |       0 |
|        101 | Hold          | Design Contracted Status |       2 |
|        102 | Pricing       | Design Contracted Status |       3 |
|        103 | Issued        | Design Contracted Status |       4 |
|        104 | In-House      | Design Contracted Status |       5 |
|        105 | Shops/layouts | Project Status           |       2 |
|        106 | Shops/layouts | Design Contracted Status |       1 |
+------------+---------------+--------------------------+---------+
```

And I have stored procedure to use this table like:

```
BEGIN

        DECLARE @Parameter1 VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @Parameter2 VARCHAR(50);
        ;WITH CTE
            AS (SELECT
                    *
                   , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY
                                          (SELECT
                                                NULL
                                          )) AS [rn]
                    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Extended , ','))
            SELECT
                 @Parameter1 = MAX(CASE
                                   WHEN [rn] = 1
                                   THEN VALUE
                                END)
                , @Parameter2 = MAX(CASE
                                   WHEN [rn] = 2
                                   THEN VALUE
                                END)
                 FROM [CTE]

        SELECT
             [GeneralKey]
            , [Label]
             FROM [General]
             WHERE [Extended] = (SELECT
                                   @Parameter1)
                  OR [Extended] = (SELECT
                                     @Parameter2)
             GROUP BY
                    [Label]
                   ,[GeneralKey]
                   , [OrderID]
             ORDER BY
                    [OrderID];
    END
```

The problem is when I execute it with `exec` instruction

```
usp_Get_StatusListByDesignType @Extended = 'Project Status,Design Contracted Status'
```

It returns repeated `Label` values:

```
+------------+---------------+
| GeneralKey |     Label     |
+------------+---------------+
|         99 | Bid Request   |
|        100 | Take-Off      |
|         63 | Take-Off      |
|        106 | Shops/layouts |
|        105 | Shops/layouts |
|        101 | Hold          |
|        102 | Pricing       |
|         64 | Hold          |
|        103 | Issued        |
|         86 | Pricing       |
|        104 | In-House      |
|         65 | Pending       |
|         66 | Contracted    |
|         67 | Dead          |
+------------+---------------+
```

As you can see I have repeated values(Label), `GROUP BY` clause isn't working on stored procedure. What am I doing wrong? Regards

**UPDATE**

As comments bellow I try to include GeneralKey with aggregate function like:

```
 SELECT
                 SUM([GeneralKey])
                , [Label]
                 FROM [General]
                 WHERE [Extended] IN (@Parameter1, @Parameter2)
                GROUP BY 
                [Label]
                ,[OrderID]
                 ORDER BY
                        [OrderID];
```

But I get same results

Comment: It is working. You will have to drop the general key if you do not want duplicates.

Comment: I dropped it, but I still getting duplicates, they just move to another position @RossBush

Comment: You'll have to drop `orderid` and `generalkey` from your `GROUP BY` clause as well... It's working exactly as it ought to though.

Comment: Just pointing out...You can use the IN operator with your parameters. -->WHERE [Extended] IN (@Parameter1,@Parameter2)

Comment: Ya, you're right @RossBush

Comment: I must need return GeneralKey, there is no way to solve duplicates if I want to return it? @JNevill

Comment: You can STUFF OrderID and/or GeneralKey into calculated fields. Then you would have 1 Label and a delimited list of matching OrderId(s)

Comment: You have two `take-off` records. One with `100` general key and one with `63` generalkey. You say you want generalkey in your ONE output record... which one? You have to tell your database which one you want. Perhaps `Max(GeneralKey)` or `Min(GeneralKey)` or `Sum(GeneralKey)`. You'll have to use an aggregate function and keep `generalkey` out of your group by.

Comment: I try it using calculated field(look my update) but I get same results @JNevill

Comment: I try it using calculated field(look my update) but I get same results @RossBush

Comment: @Pepe - I posted an example of one way to combine matching fields.

Comment: Get your `OrderID` out of the GROUP BY too... those are ALSO not distinct for each distinct `label`. They aren't even in your SELECT so I can't imagine by what logic you would put this in your `GROUP BY`. It might be a good point to take a step back from this query and learn what GROUP BY is doing as this is very rudimentary SQL logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever field you add to your `GROUP BY` is what your result set is going to be aggregated to. If one of those fields is more granular than you want, then it MUST be removed from your group by, otherwise your result set will take on that granularity.

In your case (your last attempt) you have `OrderID` in your GROUP BY. Because you have multiple `OrderID` for each `Label` your result set is going to be at the granularity of the `OrderID` when you desire it to be at the granularity of the `Label` field.

A simple query here to do what you want would be:

```
SELECT SUM(GeneralKey)
    ,Label
FROM General
WHERE Extended IN (
        @Parameter1
        ,@Parameter2
        )
GROUP BY Label;
```

If you need OrderID to be a part of this (perhaps for ordering) then you'll need to aggregate by it:

```
SELECT SUM(GeneralKey)
    ,Label
FROM General
WHERE Extended IN (
        @Parameter1
        ,@Parameter2
        )
GROUP BY Label
ORDER BY MAX(OrderId)
```

`ORDER BY` is one of the last steps the RDBMS hits when processing the data. It takes place AFTER the `GROUP BY` so you'll have to tell it how to aggregate the field by which you want to `ORDER BY` if that field is at a deeper level of granularity than you desire in your result set.

Comment: I try it but I can't use `ORDER BY MAX(OrderID)`, it just throw "Invalid column name 'OrderID'"

Comment: That's a shame. Perhaps SQL Server doesn't like that. As a workaround, stick `Max(OrderID) AS MaxOrderID` in your `SELECT` portion and then `ORDER BY MaxOrderID` at the bottom. You'll get an extra column in your output, but it will make SQL Server happy.

Comment: Oh! Or it could be the stray semicolon I left in that SQL... (just removed in an edit). Can you try to run that again with the new code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can derive a comma delimited list of matches into a calculated field.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(GeneralKey INT, Label NVARCHAR(50), OrderID INT, Extended NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT @T VALUES (99,'Bid-Request',1,'Project Status'),(100,'Take-Off',3,'Project Status'),(63,'Bid-Request',5,'Project Status'),(199,'Bid-Request',10,'Design Contracted Status')

DECLARE @Extended NVARCHAR(50) = 'Project Status,Design Contracted Status'

DECLARE @Parameter1 VARCHAR(50) ='Project Status'
DECLARE @Parameter2 VARCHAR(50) = 'Design Contracted Status'

SELECT
    T.Label,
    MInOrderId = MIN(OrderID),
    MaxOrderID = MAX(OrderID),
    GeneralKeys=
        STUFF((
            SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GeneralKey)
            FROM @T This WHERE This.Label = T.Label AND This.Extended IN(@Parameter1,@Parameter2)
            FOR XML PATH ('')) , 1, 1, ''),
    OrderIds=
        STUFF((
            SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), OrderID)
            FROM @T This WHERE This.Label = T.Label AND This.Extended IN(@Parameter1,@Parameter2)
            FOR XML PATH ('')) , 1, 1, ''),      
    ExtendedIds=
        STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ', ' +  Extended
            FROM @T This WHERE This.Label = T.Label AND This.Extended IN(@Parameter1,@Parameter2)
            FOR XML PATH ('')) , 1, 1, '')   
FROM 
    @T T
WHERE 
    Extended IN (@Parameter1,@Parameter2)
GROUP BY
    T.Label
ORDER BY
   MIN(OrderID)
```